# Unwrapping Promises in intermediary Service in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an Angular app structure, that has a Backend service to talk to a Rest API (using Restangular for example), a second service that holds the state for multiple controllers and then finally the controller.

The state holding service should be able to unwrap promises returned from the Restangular Service and provide the data to the controller. I want to the controller to be ignorant how the data is received as this is the responsibility of the service. That's why the controller shouldn't have to unwrap a promise or such.

My problem is the following:
When I unwrap the promise in the state holding service and write it to a variable the controller never gets the correct value. However when I write it to an JavaScript object property, it is eventually updating when the promise is resolved. Can anyone explain to my why the difference in behavior?

My Controller:

```
function myModuleController($scope, myService) {
  $scope.backendName1 = myService.getBackendName1();
  $scope.backendName2 = myService.getBackendName2();

}
```

My intermediary service:

```
function myService(myBackendService) {
  var backendName = '';

  var backendObject = {
    name:''
  }

  function getBackendName1() {
    myBackendService.getBackendName().then(
      function(value) {
        backendName = value;
      }
    )
    return backendName;
  }

  function getBackendName2() {
    myBackendService.getBackendName().then(
      function(value) {
        backendObject.name = value;
      }
    )
    return backendObject;
  }

  return {
    backendName: backendName,
    getBackendName1: getBackendName1,
    getBackendName2: getBackendName2
  }

}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/A31sscAqCCcmnmHfmSLR

The problem is that getBackendName1 does not get resolved,
while getBackendName2 is being resolved. See Plunker for demonstration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing a race condition here. You have 2 options. either use ui-router with resolve, and inject resolved data to controller or you need to return promises from services and wait for promise to be resolved in controller

Comment: Hi bahadir, thank you for your response. I was hoping to avoid promises in the controller. ui-router isn't an option at the moment, because right now, only small parts of the old webapp are being replaced. The routing is still done by the old webapp. 

My biggest issues is that getBackendName1 does not work, but getBackendName2 works. I am trying to understand the difference between those two solutions.

Comment: as i said earlier, this is a race condition. when you call second function, first function may have already been resolved. and it may get a response from cache. so first one fails but second one succeeds (maybe fast response from cache). if you have a slow internet connection both will not work. this is a wrong design. and you shouldn't continue on this structure

Comment: accepting this answer as we will keep the promises in the controller

Answer (score 0):

You should do assign `myService.getBackendName1` reference to scope variable and do call that on UI using interpolation directive.

**Controller**

```
function myModuleController($scope, myService) {
  $scope.backendName1 = myService.getBackendName1;
  $scope.backendName2 = myService.getBackendName2();

}
```

**HTML**

```
<body ng-app="myModule">
    <div ng-controller="myModuleController">
        <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
        <br /> Doesnt Work backendName1: {{backendName1()}}
        <br /> Works: {{backendName2.name}}
    </div>
</body>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/RPq6V2WiIyvqdrfpvEOn?p=preview) here